# Jupyter notebook not showing In[] / Out[]

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter

This is on a new bleeding edge ubuntu installed laptop where I also installed all the latest packages and tools.

The jupyter notebook also doesn't display the asterisk * when busy and execution index.

This might seem trite but I'm very used to the way notebooks work and without the order of execution and the busy asterisk I'm slowly losing my grip on reality.

Especially strange is the fact that I googled the hell out of this but it seems no one has encountered or reported it, hope its not an option I'm missing or something.

output of python --version :

```
Python 3.7.5
```

output of pip freeze :

```
absl-py==0.9.0
astor==0.8.1
attrs==19.3.0
backcall==0.1.0
bleach==3.1.0
boto3==1.12.38
botocore==1.15.38
Bottleneck==1.3.1
cachetools==4.0.0
certifi==2020.4.5.1
chardet==3.0.4
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.4.1
defusedxml==0.6.0
docutils==0.15.2
entrypoints==0.3
fasttext==0.9.1
gast==0.3.3
gensim==3.8.1
google-api-core==1.16.0
google-auth==1.13.1
google-cloud-core==1.3.0
google-cloud-storage==1.27.0
google-pasta==0.1.8
google-resumable-media==0.5.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.51.0
grpcio==1.27.1
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.9
importlib-metadata==1.5.0
ipykernel==5.1.4
ipython==7.12.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipywidgets==7.5.1
jedi==0.16.0
Jinja2==2.11.1
jmespath==0.9.5
jsonschema==3.2.0
jupyter==1.0.0
jupyter-client==5.3.4
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-contrib-core==0.3.3
jupyter-contrib-nbextensions==0.5.1
jupyter-core==4.6.1
jupyter-highlight-selected-word==0.2.0
jupyter-latex-envs==1.4.6
jupyter-nbextensions-configurator==0.4.1
Keras==2.3.1
Keras-Applications==1.0.8
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.0
kiwisolver==1.1.0
lxml==4.5.0
Markdown==3.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
matplotlib==3.1.3
mistune==0.8.4
more-itertools==8.2.0
nbconvert==5.6.1
nbextensions==0.1.0
nbformat==5.0.4
notebook==6.0.3
numexpr==2.7.1
numpy==1.16.4
pandas==1.0.1
pandocfilters==1.4.2
parso==0.6.1
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
pkg-resources==0.0.0
prometheus-client==0.7.1
prompt-toolkit==3.0.3
protobuf==3.11.3
ptyprocess==0.6.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pybind11==2.4.3
Pygments==2.5.2
pyparsing==2.4.6
pyrsistent==0.15.7
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2019.3
PyYAML==5.3
pyzmq==18.1.1
qtconsole==4.6.0
requests==2.23.0
rsa==4.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
scipy==1.4.1
Send2Trash==1.5.0
six==1.14.0
smart-open==1.10.0
tensorboard==1.14.0
tensorflow==1.14.0
tensorflow-estimator==1.14.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.8.3
testpath==0.4.4
torch==1.4.0
tornado==6.0.3
traitlets==4.3.3
urllib3==1.25.8
wcwidth==0.1.8
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug==1.0.0
widgetsnbextension==3.5.1
wrapt==1.11.2
zipp==2.2.0
```

Comment: How did you install jupyter? What's the python and jupyter version? It's not jupyterlab, is it?

Comment: Not jupyterlab but I have nbextenstions which I also tried to remove,
I've added the python --version and pip freeze on my venv to the question feel free to ask for anything else.

Comment: Thanks. Can you copy the log messages from the moment you start `jupyter` to attempt to execute a cell? It looks like the editor is not connected to the kernel.

Comment: Ok, I did a clean sweep of the whole python packages and reinstalled and it now works, I'm not sure what fixed it, probably something to do with nbextensions, I'll reinstall what I need for the notebooks to work and if it recurs I'll get back to you...

Comment: @LukaszTracewski, sorry, Lukasz, I'll be deleting this question once the bounty is over, I kind of fixed the problem and installed everything back into place and can't recreate it, I'm guessing something was messed up with the way I separated my virtual env from the local libraries though I really can't be sure by now. Thanks for the effort :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problem by:

1. deleting all my venvs
2. uninstalling all the packages from the main linux python installation (things I accidently didn't install via dpkg)
3. creating a new venv with all the GPU stuff and checking that it works
4. removing all the leftovers from the notebook stuff (mostly broken binaries)
5. adding the notebook stuff (mainly jupyter) to the packages
6. deleting the .jupyter config, recreating it and changing stuff like desktop/ initial folder/ etc...
7. running jupyter and seeing that it works fine
8. adding nbextensions and other packages the rest of my code needs